# Java. How to get month, year, day from Jspinner which is associated with java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date, jspinner

I have a spinner called Clock which holds time. But problem is that I need all data separately since that data (month, day... will be used for comparison). I have this code, this return huge strange line of string (Thu May 11 18:02:00 EEST 2017) which I cant even split and store into array (just prints whole line) nor write to file (just empty file). Is there is any way to get month, day, year from this JSpinner??

```
private void ClockStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                   

      Date date = (Date) Clock.getValue();   
      System.out.print(date);
      String dateString = null;
      SimpleDateFormat sdfr = new SimpleDateFormat("");
      dateString = sdfr.format(date);
      System.out.println( dateString );
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()
              .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
              .toLocalDate()
              .toString()
```

> 2017-01-23

## Date-time is *not* a string

Do not confuse a date-time object with a String representing its value. A date-time object can be created by parsing a string. And a date-time object can generate a string to represent its value. But the string and the date-time object are distinct and separate. So a date-time object does not “have a format”.

## Using java.time

You are using the troublesome old date-time classes (`Date` & `Calendar`) that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

If source of data (Swing) has not been updated to handle java.time types directly, convert. Look to new conversion methods added to the old classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-01-23T06:23:45.678Z

Both `java.util.Date` and `Instant` are in UTC. To determine a date, you must assign a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the world by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  // Or ZoneId.systemDefault()
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2017-01-23T01:23:45.678+05:00[America/Montreal]

Now you can extract the date-only portion. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

Your Question is not clear about your goal. If you just want to serialize this date value for later comparison, write as text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

I suggest you stick to the standard ISO 8601 formats for strings whenever possible. They are designed to minimize ambiguity. They are easy to parse by machine. They are easy to read by humans across various cultures.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

> 2017-01-23

If you do want the individual parts of year, month, and dayOfMonth, interrogate the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) object. Unlike the legacy classes, in java.time the months have sane numbering with 1-12 for January-December.

```
int year = ld.getYear() ;
int month = ld.getMonthValue() ;
int dayOfMonth = ld.getDayOfMonth() ;
```

You can also get the month as a powerful [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum object.

```
Month m = ld.getMonth();
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use Calendar object to get the day, month and year

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Calendar.MONTH starts from zero, so month is incremented by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Calendar:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY);
```

More about Calendar class in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

> The Calendar class is an abstract class that provides methods for
>   converting between a specific instant in time and a set of calendar
>   fields such as YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR, and so on, and for
>   manipulating the calendar fields, such as getting the date of the next
>   week.